# Is it legal to use IntellIJ Ultimate Edition Student License to work on commercial product

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have access to the student license of IntellIJ Ultimate Edition from my University. Is it legal to use it in my work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this entry](https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207241195-Do-you-offer-free-licenses-for-students-and-teachers-) in JetBrains' Licensing and Purchasing FAQ:

> Students and teachers are eligible to use JetBrains All Products Pack (including IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, ReSharper Ultimate and other IDEs & tools) free of charge for educational purposes. ***Educational licenses cannot be used for commercial purposes***.

Answer (score 2):

from [JetBrains TOS](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/license_educational.html)(emphasis mine):

> 3. GRANT OF RIGHTS
>
> 3.1. Unless the Toolbox Subscription has expired or this Agreement is terminated in accordance with Section 10, and subject to the terms and
>   conditions specified herein, JetBrains grants You a non-exclusive and
>   non-transferable right to use each Product covered by the Toolbox
>   Subscription for **non-commercial, educational purposes only** (including
>   conducting academic research or providing educational services)

so you're not allowed to use it on a commercial product.